# Hide view in iOS and rearrange other view with fullscreen

Tags: swift

Let's assume I have this layout design on an iPhone Portrait.
A Label (red) and an Image (blue).

[image]

But I would like to have it this way when the iPhone is in landscape. Only the image (blue).

[image]

I trying with following code but the label does not appear after return back to portrait:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
 
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

        let orient = UIDevice.current.orientation

        switch orient {
        case .portrait:
            print("Portrait")
            let ctop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 44)
            self.view.removeConstraint(ctop)
            self.labelView.isHidden = false
            break
        default:
            print("LandScape")
            let ctop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            self.view.addConstraint(ctop)
            self.labelView.isHidden = true
            break
        }
        }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            print("rotation completed")
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false?

Comment: nope, where is it?

Comment: Add imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and labelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false wherever you're defining them (or in viewDidLoad)

Comment: still not working

Comment: You should add how you define and set your views and addContraint/removeConstraint functions.
PS, instead of adding/removing the constraints, try updating the 'constant' value of the constraint.

Comment: You should add enough code so that we can run it and reproduce the problem.

Comment: work after updating the constant value! Thanks @Asteroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mixup with your `addConstraint`/`removeConstraint` logic. In the `Portrait` case you define a new `cTop` constraint and remove it (!?!) from the view - you probably want to add it.

It would be better to define both constraints right away when you create your views, and only set one to active - and then switch the `isActive` setting on both according to your new orientation. Or only define one constraint and just change the constant on it accordingly.